# how to center align table in reportview in asp.net

Tags: report, viewer

im using report viewer in visual studio 2008, in my report, everything is display correctly except table. check the image for more details

[image: http://i26.tinypic.com/2luq3rc.jpg]

the table is left aligned, how do i center align it

please help

Comment: I'm one of those that have same problem and looking for a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i moved the table, so that it was placed in the center. that solved my problem.